# Leverage Browser caching - not picking up expires header

Tags: google, page-speed, httpd.conf, google-pagespeed, amazon-cloudfront

Currently working on improving my page speed score with Google PageSpeed Insights. My biggest issue according to PageSpeed Insights is Leverage browser caching.  About 17 images come back as "no expiration specified". However, I am specifying expirations in my httpd.conf file.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"
</IfModule>
```

also when I retrieve one of the images listed with "expiration not specified" using curl and view the header, it has an expiration.

[image] 
Website is https://www.heropay.com. I am serving the images from amazon cloudfront.  CLoudfront is set to use origin header so that shouldn't be the issue.

At a loss where to go from here to get this fix.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check if mod_expires module is enabled or not.

Comment: @Aakash double checked.  It is

Comment: What happens when you run the whole page through webpagetest.org? Everything seems good at my end.

Comment: Google may not recrawl the images every time you run the test.  Maybe it was using cached data from before you made changes?      What happens now that it has been a while?